# jQuery addition function giving me NaN

Tags: dom, jquery

I am using the following function to add all of my line totals together. Each of the totals will be a decimal number such as 23.45 . When the user enters any qty into any of text input boxes it should fire the function, but all I'm getting at the moment in grandtotal is NaN, who's nan is it and why is she messing with my script?

By the way, each of the linetotals is a span, which is filled with the line total calculation once a quantity is entered into the qty text box.

So basically, user comes along, selects a price from the line one drop down, so lets say 20.00 , they then enter the quantity into the text box qty, let's say 2, jQuery then multiplies qty by priceeach and output into the span with the id linetotal1. What I want to do is add all of the linetotals together for a grand total, but lets say if they don't enter anything into line 2, linetotal2, 3, 4, 5 will them be empty.

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('input').on('keyup', function () {
           linetotal1 =  $('#linetotal1').text(),
            linetotal2 =  $('#linetotal2').text(),
             linetotal3 =  $('#linetotal3').text(),
              linetotal4 =  $('#linetotal4').text(),
               linetotal5 =  $('#linetotal5').text(),
    grandtotal = parseFloat(linetotal1) + parseFloat(linetotal2) + parseFloat(linetotal3) +     parseFloat(linetotal4) + parseFloat(linetotal5);
    $('#grandtotal').text(grandtotal);
       });  });
   </script>
```

Comment: If any of the `parseFloat` calls returns `NaN`, the result will be `NaN`. That value is returned if the input cannot be converted to a number. E.g. `parseFloat('')` return `NaN`.

Comment: How can I add an if empty to each one, so it will ignore it ?

Comment: hahaha... "who's NaN".. epic... Anyway, you said text boxes right? then you must be using `$(...).val()` instead of `text()`.

Comment: linetotal are spans with the contents generated from adding two other elements together. All im doing it adding the contents of each span together, but some spans will be empty until a calculation for that line is made.

Comment: linetotal1 =  parseFloat($('#linetotal1').text()) || 0 ,tried this yet?

Comment: So basically, user comes along, selects a price from the line one drop down, so lets say 20.00 , they then enter the quantity into the text box qty, lets say 2 , jquery then multiplies qty by priceeach and output into the span with the id linetotal1 . What I want to do is add all of the linetotals together for a grand total, but lets say if they dont enter anything into line 2, linetotal2 , 3, 4 , 5 will them be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just loop from 1-5, and have the value default to `0` if it's a blank string:

```
var rawValue, grandtotal = 0;

for(var i=1; i<6; i++)
{
     rawValue = $.trim($('#linetotal' + i).text());
     if(rawValue == '') rawValue = 0;
     grandtotal += parseFloat(rawValue);
}

$('#grandtotal').text(grandtotal);
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fRFFE/1/)**

---

If you wanted to do something a bit fancier with jQuery you could select each of the spans based on the ID starting with `linetotal`. This would work if you added more spans, where as with the `for` loop, you'd have to update the count. It would be better if the spans all had a common class, which you could use to easily select them.

```
var rawValue, grandtotal = 0;

$('span[id^="linetotal"]').each(function(i, elem){
     rawValue = $.trim($(this).text());
     if(rawValue == '') rawValue = 0;
     grandtotal += parseFloat(rawValue);
});

$('#grandtotal').text(grandtotal);
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92LS7/1/)**

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').on('keyup', function () {
  var rawValue, grandtotal = 0;

for(var i=1; i<6; i++)
{
     rawValue = $.trim($('#linetotal' + i).text());
     if(rawValue == '') rawValue = 0;
     grandTotal += parseFloat(rawValue);
}

$('#grandtotal').text(grandtotal);
        });  });

Comment: Ah, I had an uppercase T in `grandtotal`, I've edited to fix. Also added demo.

Comment: Wow cool, thanks for that, the second one works really well ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this by loop, i have done this before for my client check if my code helps you

```
    var disValue = new Array();
    var this_size = document.getElementsByName("myVal").length;
    sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<this_size; i++)
    {
          disValue[i] = document.getElementsByName("myVal")[i].value;
    }

    for (i=0; i<this_size; i++)
    {
        sum = parseFloat(sum)+ parseFloat(disValue[i]);
    }

 if (sum != 0) {
document.getElementById("disc_test").innerHTML="<?php echo $this->__('You are saving') ?> "+sum +" <?php echo $this->__('on this order') ?>!";
 }
```

ignore php tags :)